# How to write batch script to find files before or after a certain date time?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am currently using this script to find files after a certain date.

```
forfiles /P directory /S /D +%day%/%month%/%year%
```

Problem is, I cannot find ways to make it time-specific. E.g., I want to find files after `23/03/2017 17:30` (5:30pm).

Is there a batch script that allows me to find files before/after a certain `date time`?

If possible, I would not like to use `forfiles` due to its date parameter format being region-specific.

Comment: `forfiles` does not regard the time at all, it only regards the date of the last modification; you may be interested in the [`~t` modifier](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of argument references or [`for` variables](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html), but the returned date/time is also region-dependent (and in minute resolution ony, I think); you might be interested in this: [`wmic`](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)`DataFile where (Name="C:\\TEMP\\test.txt") get LastModified`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For region/locale independent solution, use next PowerShell code snippet:

```
$closeTime = Get-Date -Year 2017 -Month 3 -Day 18 -Hour 17 -Minute 30
Get-ChildItem D:\bat\so -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $closeTime } |
        ForEach-Object {
            # do something with a file
            '{0} {1}' -f $_.LastWriteTime, $_.FullName
        }
```

**Edit**: unfortunately, my first attempt is wrong as it simulates next PowerShell code snippet (displays only files *after `17:30` **in each day*** not *after  a specified day, `17:30`*):

```
Get-ChildItem D:\bat\so -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $(Get-Date -Year 2017 -Month 3 -Day 18) } | 
        Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.Hour -ge 17 -and $_.LastWriteTime.Minute -ge 30} | 
            ForEach-Object {
                 # do something with a file
                '{0} {1}' -f $_.LastWriteTime, $_.FullName
            }
```

[`FORFILES.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) does not offer such a possibility. However, you can check time using [`IF`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) to *conditionally* perform a command  on each file as follows:

```
==> FORFILES /P SO /D +18/03/2017 /C "cmd /c if "@ftime" GEQ "17:30:00" (echo @fdate @ftime GEQ @path) else (echo @fdate @ftime LSS @path)"

20/03/2017 19:59:05 GEQ "d:\bat\SO\42911145.bat"
21/03/2017 08:52:49 LSS "d:\bat\SO\42918825.bat"
22/03/2017 13:44:52 LSS "d:\bat\SO\numberedFiles.bat"

==>
```

Omit `else` branch if unnecessary:

```
==> FORFILES /P SO /D +18/03/2017 /C "cmd /c if "@ftime" GEQ "17:30:00" echo @fdate @ftime GEQ @path"

20/03/2017 19:59:05 GEQ "d:\bat\SO\42911145.bat"

==>
```

Read [`TIME` - Display or set the system time](https://ss64.com/nt/time.html) article as well for more info about regional specific time format.